# I ended up with two DIFFERENT estus flasks (+2 and +7). Will this break my game?

Tags: technical-issues, mods, dark-souls

Does anyone have any info about what this will do to the game and the best way to handle it? I found it in the chest at Firelink Shine where you're supposed to get back important dropped items. I opened the chest out of curiosity and it doesn't tell you what you're about to pick up (it just says "loot chest?" or something). The item was estus flask +7 which I NEVER DROPPED. (But I did have temporarily for about 5 min)

I used a game save editor to try and improve my survival. I gave myself a set of slightly better armor (Gold-Hemmed Black set) a better weapon (Ghost Blade) and a fire keeper soul (intending to upgrade flask later). After reading that cheating fire keeper souls messes up your game, I went back to the editor and replaced the soul with something generic. I hadn't read anything about cheating in a better flask causing problems with this editor, so I just went ahead and replaced my full +1 flask with a +7 flask. Then I discovered I could not pick up items. I changed the flask back to a +1 and everything worked fine again. (playing the game, I upgraded the +1 to a +2 the normal non-cheating way) ...But just now I picked up the +7 flask out of that magic recovery chest by accident. Now I have two in my inventory and they both filled at a bonfire. Google is not helping, using "2" or "two" (flasks) gives me results for "dark souls II" instead. Other searches bring up the concept of how many refills you have. I dropped a random item and was able to pick it up. Does that mean I'm fine? Is there a way to make sure I do NOT have the "can't pick up items/keys" glitch?

Any help would be appreciated.

XBox 360, patched Dark Souls, Dark Souls Save Editor by Jappi88 version 2.5 http://www.360haven.com/forums/threads/8065-Final-Dark-Souls-Save-editor-V-2-5-0-0

Comment: There is a newer version of the save editor.

Comment: @Mondrianaire Yes, but I need the version that does not require an _additional_ program to use. Downloading one is enough for me. Version 2.5 does not require a 3rd party program such as Modio, 360revolution, or Horizon. Version 3.0 is a completely different program (not an update of 2.5) and the creator did not include that type of feature in the new version.

Answer (score 3):

Of course there is no way to know 100% that your save game is not corrupted after modifying a savegame, but I have had multiple Estus after modding my save multiple times and never have had a problem with it.

It is to note that the game considers different Estus to be **different items from one another**. When you upgrade your estus, your +1 estus gets deleted and it loads a +2 estus in its place. This explains *how* it is possible to have two at the same time.

Comment: So far I have also picked up one key. It's good to know that at least someone has had multiple flasks & everything still worked. I found that it wouldn't let me update my original +2 flask anymore, but I am able to drink from the +7 flask.

Unfortunately it won't matter anymore. The XBox is now refusing to read the USB drive, claiming it's unformatted. (But it hadn't left the box since I last played the game.) XBox support says "insert drive _after_ XBox is on" fixes it. I use USB drives often & I've only had this problem with Dark Souls. Their "fix" doesn't work this time though. Oh well.